# Will Rhodes framework allow me to work with archives?

Tags: ruby, rhodes

Is it possible to uncompress archives using the Rhodes framework? What kind of archives are supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it's based on ruby, I think you can use the ruby wrapper for [libarchive](https://bitbucket.org/winebarrel/libarchive-ruby/src) or [ZLib](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/zlib/rdoc/index.html) (Implementation of deflate-algorithm, gzip format). If you want to use a pure ruby library, try [Zliby](http://zliby.rubyforge.org/) which is a replacement for Zlib.

libarchive supports the following archive types (Source http://code.google.com/p/libarchive/wiki/LibarchiveFormats)

> **Filter Support**
>
> Libarchive 2.6 and later supports
>   multiple filters when reading
>   archives. Libarchive 3.0 and later
>   supports multiple filters when writing
>   archives.
>
> ```
> gzip (read and write, uses zlib)
> bzip2 (read and write, uses bzlib)
> compress (read and write, uses an internal implementation)
> uudecode (read only)
> separate command-line compressors with fixed-signature auto-detection
> xz and lzma (read and write using liblzma)
> lzma (if you lack liblzma, you can get read-only lzma support through the
> ```
>
> lzmadec library; this will likely be
>   dropped as soon as liblzma is stable
>   and widely-available)
>       Starting with libarchive 2.7, most of the above will fall back to using
>   command-line tools if the libraries
>   were unavailable at build time. Note
>   that the command-line tools are
>   usually slower than using the
>   libraries directly.
>
> **Archive Formats Supported**
>
> ```
> tar (read and write, including GNU extensions)
> pax (read and write, including GNU and star extensions)
> cpio (read and write, including odc and newc variants)
> ISO9660 (read only, including Joliet and Rockridge extensions, with
> ```
>
> some limitations; write support
>   starting with libarchive 2.9)
>       Zip (read only, with some limitations, uses zlib; write support
>   starting with libarchive 2.8)
>       mtree (read and write, uses OpenSSL libraries for creating and
>   verifying cryptographic hashes)
>       shar (write only)
>       ar (read and write, including BSD and GNU/SysV variants)
>       empty (read only; in particular, note that no other format will accept
>   an empty file)
>       raw (read only, starting in libarchive 2.8)
>       xar (read only, starting in libarchive 2.8)

Comment: Thanks, but they have a stripped down version of the interpreter. I think not a lot of gems can build on that.

Comment: I've looked over zliby's source, and I noticed the only dependency is StringIO, which is listed as supported in rhodes's documentation. I will try it, and let you know :)